# How to convert user object to name

Tags: discord, discord.py

Currently the output of the user is `Team_<@378014902620520451>`. How do i convert this to a username of the player?

```
                team_one_capatain = []
                team_two_capatain = []

                team_one_capatain.append(random.choice(queue))
                team_two_capatain.append(random.choice(queue))

                for captain_one in team_one_capatain:
                    for captain_two in team_two_capatain:
                
                        """ queue.remove(team_one_capatain)
                        queue.remove(team_two_capatain) """
                        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.teal())
                        embed.add_field(name=f'Team_{captain_one}', value=None, inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name='PLAYERS', value=',\n'.join(queue), inline=True)
                        embed.add_field(name=f'Team_{captain_two}', value=None, inline=True)
                        embed_message = await ready_channel.send(embed=embed)
                        for i in range(0, len(queue)):
                            await embed_message.add_reaction(emoji_numbers[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `captain_one` is of type `discord.User` or `discord.Member`, you can use `captain_one.display_name`. The documentation explains the `display_name` attribute:

> For regular users this is just their username, but if they have a guild specific nickname then that is returned instead.

([source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.display_name))

Other attributes you might be interested in:

- [discord.User.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.name) (same for discord.Member)
- [discord.User.discriminator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.discriminator) (same for discord.Member)
- [discord.Member.nick](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.nick)

Comment: I have tried this, but it gives me an error of `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'display_name'` ? @wheelercj

Comment: You will need to get a `discord.User` or a `discord.Member` object at some point. Since `captain_one` is apparently a str of a user's mention, I would look at where that came from.

Comment: ahhhhh i seee, i think i understand what you are saying. `queue = []
    for players in queue_channel.members:
        queue.append(players.mention) #you can change this to display_name/name/nick/mention 
        if len(queue) == int(config.queue_size): 
            queue_check.stop()`